# modify an array based on another array

Tags: javascript

I have a reference array of phrases like this:

```
const reference = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
```

and I want to join some of the elements of above array based on another array so if `another` is this:

```
const another = ["your", "they are"];
```

The the result would be like :

```
result = ["your", "majesty", "they are", "ready"];
```

another situation to be more clear:

```
const reference = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
const another = ["your majesty", "they are ready"];
result = ["your majesty", "they are ready"];
```

or:

```
const reference = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
const another = ["majesty they", "ready"];
result = ["your", "majesty they", "are", "ready"];
```

and of course if there is an empty `another` we get the same reference as the result:

```
const reference = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
const another = [];
result = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
```

Comment: Did you have a question? What result is your current attempt giving you?

Comment: This just sounds like a FANG coding interview question; what is your current code that you have, to show that you have tried to do this already, and see what the errors are

Comment: @Samathingamajig  I'm not sure what FANG is, but this question - or questions using the *exact same phrase* - has been asked numerous times recently.  So, on that basis, I would agree that these do look like interview questions or, at least, homework.

Comment: @ATD FANG/FAANG is the shorthand for Facebook, Amazon/Apple, Netflix, and Google (the Big Tech companies), and are notorious for having a difficult interview process with questions like these

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thanks.  I'm not sure what it says about the job applicants, if they have to ask for help for interview questions.

Comment: @ATD well, the interview questions are live, so you wouldn't be able to google/stackoverflow the question, especially if you have to ask on a new SO thread

Comment: @Samathingamajig  So how do they know about the questions that they are going to be asked?  It seems strange that so many people are asking the same, or very similar, questions all in a short space of time.  Do the FANG companies publish the questions?

Comment: @ATD They do release previous questions, and there are resources like codewars and leetcode (freemium) and others like algoexpert.io (paid) that have video explanations of how to solve these types of problems. (this is not an advertisement for any of these platforms)

Comment: @Samathingamajig  Ah, ok - it's like us being shown exam papers from previous years when I was at school.  And, I thought companies like those asked things like:  "If you were an animal, what animal would you be and why?"

Answer (score 2):

```js
const reference = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
//const another = ["your", "they are"];
//const another = ["your majesty", "they are ready"];
//const another = ["majesty they", "ready"];
const another = [];

function formatResult(reference, another) {
  //1: another is [] then return reference
  if (another.length == 0) {
    return reference;
  } else {
    //2: format the reference array with another array
    another.forEach(x => {
      var words = x.split(' ');
      if (words.length > 1) {
        var index = 0;
        var sindex = 0; // if the index are countiues
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          //find this word in refference array.
          index = reference.indexOf(words[i]);
          if (i == 0) {
            sindex = index;
          } else {
            //check if the index are next to each other, if not break the loop
            if (sindex != index) {
              break;
            }
          }
          sindex++;
        }
        if (index == sindex - 1) //to check all the index in the order
        {
          var startIndex = index - (words.length - 1);
          //update reference array with another array.
          reference.splice(startIndex, words.length, x);
        }
      }
    })
  }
  return reference;
}
var result = formatResult(reference, another);
console.log(result);
```

```html
Does this satisfy your question?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the first input array using `Array.filter` to remove the items which are included on the second input array.

And the result can be made by joining those filtered first array and second array using `Array.concat`.

```js
function format(input1, input2) {
  let result = input1.filter((item) => !input2.some((item2) => item2.includes(item)));
  return result.concat(input2);
}

const reference1 = ["your", "majesty", "they", "are", "ready"];
const another1 = ["majesty they", "ready"];
const result1 = format(reference1, another1);
console.log(result1);
```

Comment: It looks like this implementation does not distinguish between `they majesty` and `majesty they`. But I don't know if the order is matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```js
var ref = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "h"];
var ano = ["a", "b c", "e f", "d", "f", "g h i", "j"];
var res = [];

ano = ano.filter(a => a.split(" ").length>1); // remove single words from ano

while(ano.length) {
    var ano_words = ano.shift();
    var len = ano_words.split(" ").length;
  
    while(ref.length>len) {
        var ref_words = ref.slice(0,len).join(" ");
        if (ref_words == ano_words) { 
            res.push(ref_words);
            ref = ref.slice(len,ref.length);
            break;
        }
        res.push(ref.shift());
    }  
}

res = [...res, ...ref]; 

console.log(res);  // ["a", "b c", "d", "e f", "g h i", "j", "h"]
```